# How to send multiple vectors to a SimpleRNN?

Tags: keras, recurrent-neural-network, keras-layer

I have 'n' no. of vectors of 'm' size each. I need to send them to a SimpleRNN of keras. The vectors should be send such that each neuron of the RNN takes a vector(eg: vector1 to neuron1, vector2 t neuron2 etc) along with hidden state of previous input vector.

I have tried concatenating them, but this distorts the nature of the input.

`input1 = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(input1)

input2 = Dense(20, activation = "relu")(input2)`

I need to send these vectors(input1 and input2) to the RNN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`tf.stack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack) in Tensorflow or `keras.backend.stack` in Keras. This operator:

> Stacks a list of rank-R tensors into one rank-(R+1) tensor

Based on your code, `Dense layers` can be stacked in the following way:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inps1 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(30,))
inps2 = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(30,))
dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(inps1)
dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(20, activation='relu')(inps2)

dense = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.stack([x[0], x[1]], axis=1), output_shape=(None, 2, 20))([dense1, dense2])

rnn = tf.keras.layers.SimpleRNN(100)(dense)
```

Comment: will stacking the vectors together make sure that the 1st vector goes to 1st neuron, 2nd one to 2nd neuron and so on upto n?

Comment: when I try `out = stack([input1, input2], axis=1)
    out = SimpleRNN(50, activation="relu")(out)
` It gives me the error `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Dense1 feed into the network at t=0, dense2 at time=1 and so on.

Comment: @yaminigoel Lambda layer needed.

Comment: I am receiving `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer simple_rnn_1: expected shape=(None, None, 20), found shape=(None, None, 2, 20)
`  and when I change the output shape to `output_shape=(None, None, 20)` I get `ValueError: Error when checking target: expected simple_rnn_1 to have shape (50,) but got array with shape (1,)
`